# How to change WP c4fToolkit:TimeSpanPicker value format

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have a countdown timer in the page but in the format hh:mm:ss and I need in mm:ss. Is there any way to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this property in your xaml in TimeSpanPicker.

```
ValueStringFormat="{}{0:mm:ss}"
```